# Succinct notation for the set of largest equivalence classes of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Let $S $ be any set and $R\subseteq S \times S$ be an equivalence realation on $S$.

I would like to express succinctly that set $W$ is any of the largest $R$-equivalence classes of $S$.

Is there any more succinct notation than the following two?

1. $ U = \{ T \in 2^S \mid \forall a,b \in T: (a,b) \in R \} $
   $ W = \textit{any set in}  \arg \max_{V \in U}|V| $
2. $ W = \textit{any set in}  \arg \max_{V \in \{ T \in 2^S \mid \forall a,b \in T: (a,b) \in R \}}|V| $

Comment: How about "$W$ is any of the largest $R$-equivalence classes of $S$"?

Comment: $W\in S/R$, and for any $V\in S/R$: $|V|\leq|W|$, using [quotient by an equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_by_an_equivalence_relation).

Comment: or "$W$ is an $R$-equivalence class of maximal cardinality"

Comment: By the way, the existence of such $W$ is not guaranteed. E.g. if $S$ is the set of natural numbers, and we let $n_1\sim n_2$ iff there is some $k$ such that $2^k\leq n_i<2^{k+1}$ for both $i$.